# Percentage function on bool series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Using a function similar to this:

```
def percentage(part, whole):
    return 100 * float(part)/float(whole)
```

I can get the percentage calling the function:

```
percentage(215,413)
```

But how do I take a bool series and get the percentage of True and False?

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5) +5)

s > 5

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Desired output is percentage of True values in the series (60% in the example above).  Do I need to `map` a function to get the output?  Please show me the best way to do this.  thanks

Comment: Use `(s>5).sum()`?

Comment: (s>5).sum()/len(s). then 1 -  (s>5).sum()/len(s)

Answer (score 6):

Just calculate the mean of the boolean pandas series. Since True is mapped to 1 and False is mapped to 0, you will end up getting the percentage by simply calculating the mean.:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5) +5)
(s > 5).mean()
0.59999999999999998
```

Answer (score 1):

The built in Series operators are another handy way to do this:

```
s.gt(5).mean()
```